# FA for w when length of w is even or divisible by 3

Tags: finite-automata

I want to construct a FA for the language

$\{w \in \{a,b\} | $length of w is either even or divisible by 3$\}$.

I've been playing around with some FAs, but I can't seem to create one that does the job. I can easily create one that accepts words with even length, and also one that accepts words with lengths divisible by 3, but I am unable to combine these.

This is my attempt:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, you need to add one more node,and to add another final state for $q_0$ because that the length of empty string equal to zero which is even. try this:[image]

I made some tests:

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: That makes sense! The aspect I don't understand about NFA, is that surely the word length must be known before so that the correct 'path' is chosen at the start? If for instance, you have a word of length 4, if you take the path that goes to state q3 first, you will end up not having the word accepted - although it should be.

Comment: @Leonhard It's enough that exist at least one path that accept the word and that's it, you don't care about the other pathes.

Comment: You can eliminate q3 and transition directly from q0 to q6.  Then q0 need not be final.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution is to use a DFA with 6 states which count the number of letters seen so far, modulo 6. This is a DFA with 6 states $q_0,\ldots,q_5$, and transition function $\delta(q_i,\sigma) = q_{i+1 \bmod{6}}$. The accepting states are $\{q_0,q_2,q_3,q_4\}$, since a number is even or divisible by 3 iff its residue modulo 6 is one of 0,2,3,4.

Using Myhill–Nerode theory, you can easily show that this is the minimal DFA for the language. Using an NFA with multiple initial states, you can improve this to 5 states: have two starting states $q_0^{(2)},q_0^{(3)}$ which also double as accepting states, states $q_1^{(2)},q_1^{(3)},q_2^{(3)}$, and transitions $\delta(q_i^{(m)},\sigma) = \{q^{(m)}_{i+1 \bmod{m}}\}$. This is likely the minimal number of states for this type of NFA.